# SSR - Status code 301 is missing when the page comes from the cache ( Always returns 200 )

Tags: redirect, server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

We currently have a problem with SSR optimized engine. The scenario is that a product has been removed or renamed on the catalog, and the user tends to access that old none existing URL directly. Then we have implemented a redirected behavior sending a status code of 301 so that the customer gets redirected to a relevant page where its URL is retrieved from BE. (Through a generic HTTP interceptor catchError)

```
catchError((error: any) => {
 if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
  ...
  this.response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  this.response.set('location',this.service.urlBuilder(redirectUrl));
  return this.setMovedPermanentlyStatus();
  }
}
```

However, we also have those pages cached, so the next time that the page comes from the cache, it returns 200 instead of 301, which we tried to implement in the first place. We tried to rule out those with 301 not to be treated like others, but it still returns with 200 when they're coming from the cache. ( By extending SSR optimized engine with an exception like )

```
   protected fallbackToCsr(response: Response, filePath: string, callback: SsrCallbackFn): void {
    if (response.statusCode !== HttpResponseStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
      response.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
      callback(undefined, this.getDocument(filePath));
    }
  }
```

We're looking for a solution to ensure that all 'the redirected pages' will always respond with 301 and not 200, even if they come from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

> By extending SSR optimized engine

How did you extended (and used) optimized engine? I'm curious about this, because as I see it, the instance is hardcoded (and not injected), just like this:

```
// apply optimization wrapper if optimization options were defined
    return optimizationOptions
      ? new OptimizedSsrEngine(engineInstance, optimizationOptions)
          .engineInstance
      : engineInstance;
```

If you actually managed to use your own instance of Optimized Engine, then you could do this:
Override renderResponse

```
  protected renderResponse(
    filePath: string,
    options: any,
    callback: (err?: Error | null, html?: string) => void
  ): void {
    super.renderResponse(filePath, options, callback);
    const response: Response = options.res || options.req.res;
    if (response.statusCode === HttpResponseStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
      // remove the result from cache so that it's executed again
      const request: Request = options.req;
      const key = this.getRenderingKey(request);
      this.renderingCache.clear(key);
    }
  }
```

However, this might not be too optimum. One way to improve: Use an additional internal Map<string,string> cache, and add code to store the `renderingKey` of the request and the `Location` value of the header inside the `if` above; so that, *before* calling `super.renderResponse` you will add code to check the map with the key; if present, then redirect to the result, and avoid the call to `super.renderResponse`.

Additionally, supposing that it's not possible to extend from `OptimizedSsrEngine`, the way to go would be to add a **middleware** on express server (see at `server.ts` file in your project), and make the implementation at low-level: the same approach, using a `Map` to store the redirects. You could add one middleware before the default to check that map, and calling `next()` only if the request key it's not in the map; and one after, to store the request key and the redirect if it's a redirect (ensure to add a call to `next()` from the default implementation).

Comment: Thanks @Axel A. About your question I have my own instance of OptimizedSsrEngine by extending NgExpressEngineDecorator and making a reference to it in Server.ts and it works. I tried your first approach and I managed to get it work. However the response `statusCode` is returned as null while it's 301 on the `fallBackToCsr()` method. It seems setting headers for renamed products leads to `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` which means I'm trying to set headers after the response is sent. That's the thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/5863 Is a known issue for 'renamed' version of urls. Do you have any insight over it? Seems the url value replacement takes place in OOTB and reacts asynchronously with where I set the headers in the interceptor.

Comment: Thanks for your response @hybridfish ; I cannot imagine how is that `fallBackToCsr` receives a `response` whose `statusCode` is `301`, and in the same flow after return of renderResponse method it would be `null` (since it seems it's constant and it's get with the same code). I'd think that it's actually fallBackToCsr which is not receiving the proper `statusCode` when expected. For example, when the server is still processing the first request (which would turn out in 301) and there is a new request in parallel which is derived to `fallBackToCsr`.

Comment: In the end, I'm afraid I don't have other suggestion than the one that would use middleware. Even more, maybe the solution could involve a third-party caching service (Akamai, or any other similar?) I think it's just that Spartaucs code should address this kind of redirects as something OOB and then a new feature should be introduced in a new version.

FYI, there is a thread discussion about caching that redirect: https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/question/0D50f00005Rtq5oCAB/can-i-have-akamai-cache-the-result-of-a-redirect?language=en_US